# Редактирование UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Необходимо сделать небольшой пробел между буквами при вводе текста используя UITextFiled. Использую attributedText, все работает, но когда мне надо подправить текст, скажем исправить букву в середине, буква добавляется в конец слова, а не в то место, где я указал.

Код:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    [self updateTypedText:string andTextField:textField range:range];
    return YES;
}

- (void)updateTypedText:(NSString*) string andTextField:(UITextField*)textField range:(NSRange)range
{
    if (textField == _emailTextField) {
        NSString *newString = textField.text;
        NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: newString];
        [attributedString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
                                 value:@(2)
                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, newString.length)];

        textField.attributedText = attributedString;
    }

}
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: а зачем вы range передаете, если все равно его не используете

Comment: Пытался использовать, но так и не понял как.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    if (range.location < textField.text.length) {
            return YES;
    }

    [self updateTypedText:string andTextField:textField];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы хотите добавить букву, то воспользуйтесь этим методом `NSMutableString insertString:atIndex:`

Если хотите заменить, то метод `NSMutableString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:` или `NSMutableString replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:`(последний метод заменит вс вхождения подстроки)

Answer (score 0):

Вот смотрите,

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    [self updateTypedText:string andTextField:textField range:range];
    return YES;
}
```

возвращая в конце YES, вы говорите, что буква под таким то индексом, или же текст, какой то длинны, в какой то индекс будет вставлен в текст, НО, возвращая NO, и делаю вот такую штуку

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
        [self updateTypedText:string andTextField:textField range:range];
        return NO;
    }
```

вы будете вставляет ей тот символ, под тот индекс, который вам нужен.